# custom-set-variables add blank space on subsequent uses

Tags: emacs, elisp

I followed the [emacs haskell tutorial](https://github.com/serras/emacs-haskell-tutorial/blob/master/tutorial.md), and couldn't understand some of its language regarding the use of `custom-set-variables` in the text quoted below. It seems that `custom-set-variables` should be used in one way on first usage, and another way (with added blank space) on subsequent uses.

My questions are:

What exactly should the second usage be?

Why is it that `custom-set-variables` should be used differently on first and subsequent usage?

Thanks

-- quoted code --

> To enable it, add
>
> ```
> (custom-set-variables '(haskell-process-type 'cabal-repl))
> ```
>
> to your personal configuration file. However, if your personal configuration file already *has* a `custom-set-variables` command, you'll need to instead add a blank space and then `'(haskell-process-type 'cabal-repl)` before its closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just saying that you can include multiple custom variables in one invocation of `custom-set-variables`. So if you already have

```lisp
(custom-set-variables
  '(some-variable 'some-value))
```

you can add to it like so:

```lisp
(custom-set-variables
  '(some-variable 'some-value)
  '(haskell-process-type 'cabal-repl))
```